# The page I printed with PDFTron in Windows 7 comes out of the printer in a distorted way

Tags: c#, pdftron

Hello I am sending and printing a file with PDFTron to the printer. But the page is broken.
I have no such problem in Windows 10. What is the problem?

Comment: Is Win7 support important for your users/customers? Can you provide the input file? Can you provide screenshot/photo showing the distorted output? Does the distortion happen with any printer (virtual or physical)? If specific printers, which one and why is it important? To assist you, please answer all the above.

Comment: Hello Ryan.
I print using Bullzip on Windows 7. My pages do not fit in the pdf page,
it is moving and I cannot adjust the page orientation either. This is also the case when printing from the printer.

Comment: There is no problem printing with Microsoft Print to PDF on Windows 10. I am also printing successfully from the printer.How do I use this in windows 7. My customers computers are Windows 7 pro.

Comment: The Windows 7 compatible dll I downloaded from your site gives me this error.PDFNet, Version = 7.0.17.2233, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 36167be3f67ac39c

Comment: "gives me this error.PDFNet" this is a new error? If so, what changed from what you were doing before? What .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: "This is also the case when printing from the printer" which printer is this? Can you try the virtual printer "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"? How is that output? Also, how exactly are you printing, please update your question with the code you ran.

Comment: My costumers has Canon printers. Also, pages are corrupted when outputting pdf in Adobe PDF driver.

Comment: There is no problem on Windows 10. Again, when printing with Adobe PDF driver on windows 10, my application freezes and closes.

Comment: Codes is https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/299GXBzkQJ/

Comment: "The Windows 7 compatible dll I downloaded from your site gives me this error.PDFNet, Version = 7.0.17.2233, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 36167be3f67ac39c" I got this error while developing on windows 10. "Version = 7.0.17.2233 dll" worked fine on Windows 7, but the pages are corrupt. In other words, the pdf content does not fit on the page and the setPapersize () function does not work.

Comment: @Ryan Hi Ryan.The problem is on both windows 7 and windows 10. Pages get corrupted when I output my pdf file with Adobe PDF and Bullzip PDF printers. Also, the pages are not rotating. No problem when I print to Microsoft Print to PDF printer. 
Sample pictures are below.
1. Output from Bullzip PDF or Adobe PDF
2.Microsoft print to pdf printer

1. https://resmim.net/i/A39tE
2. https://resmim.net/i/A3R3X

Comment: @Ryan What is your suggestion for a solution?

Comment: Does this issue occur with any PDF file you try? What about the PDF files that come with our SDK samples? If specific file(s) can you provide one?

Comment: @Ryan Hi Ryan. https://dosya.co/clhhby05v520/2-SIEMENS+S7+1200+VE+ÇALIŞMASI.pdf.html
https://dosya.co/ick6ejo0on7m/1-GENEL+KAVRAMLAR.pdf.html

Comment: @Ryan These two files are some of the ones I have been having trouble printing with Adobe PDF and Bullzip PDF printers. Although I set the page size in the code with the SetPaperSize () function, the page size does not change when printing on these printers. Same when I print from test files in SDK. When I say print more than one on one page, for example, page size 210mmx297mm for A4, that's okay. But the page size is 297mmx210mm, so I have a problem when the page is horizontal.

Comment: @Ryan Code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/96RYSXrsqN/

Comment: " the page size does not change when printing on these printers" yes it appears these printers are ignoring the specified printer settings. What is wrong with just SetAutoCenter(true), SetAutoRotate(true) and  SetScaleType(e_ScaleType_ReduceToOutputPage)? That should give you the best output across printers. Why exactly is SetPaperSize(Rect) important?

Comment: @Ryan Hi Ryan . I solved the problem. How do I set up padding and margin within the page with Pdftron?

Comment: Glad to hear. As for your new question. PDF files technically do not have "padding" or "margins", so there is no specific API. You can of course edit the PDF page to make larger or smaller. Perhaps the PDFTron forums will have an answer for your particular question. Otherwise, you should start a new question on SO here.